# Terminate batch job quietly

Tags: bash, shell-script, batch-jobs

What signal code do I use with the kill command to terminate a background job quietly? Or perhaps an environment variable setting in the batch environment?

Specifically, the "[1]+  Terminated           *jobname* message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You can start the tasks you kill in a subshell, then the "mother" shell won't notify you about terminating tasks.

Note that this smells very heavily of an XY problem. You seem to be using `kill` as means of job control within a script – that's probably a design mistake – and now you have to deal with the annoying messages that tell you something was killed. Instead of fixing the killing, you're trying to fix the displaying! This is a bit of speculation, but it would seem to me that you'd be better of figuring out a better way than killing, rather than figuring out how to hide messages.